# file not foundのエラーを解消したい

Tags: network

・最終的に行いたいこと
YYYのディレクトリで開発したプロジェクトを、ブラウザでIPアドレスから動作確認できるようにしたい

・現状
サーバ上でプロジェクトの開発をしています。
teratermでSSH接続し、ローカルのブラウザで随時動作確認の作業をしております。IPアドレスでいままでは接続していました。

新しいディレクトリが必要となり、今まで作業していたXXXディレクトリを、YYYに変えました`mv XXX YYYY`。
すると、ブラウザ上で`File not found.`と表示されてしまうようになりました。
mv実行後、XXXは存在しているのですが、中身のファイルはほとんど削除されてあり、数個ファイルが入っています（なぜ消えたのか、なぜ一部残っているのかわからない。）
YYYの中身は合っています。

どういった原因が考えられるでしょうか？

windows10、teraterm、ブラウザはchromeで閲覧

追記。

1. mvコマンドを実行し、ディレクトリのrenameを実行したつもりですが、IPアドレスの接続先はXXXになっているのでしょうか？

Comment: もう少し詳しく記載できますか？例えば、そのディレクトリはApacheのVirtualHostなどでDirectory指定やAliasが指定されていたり、そもそもWEBの環境がどういった環境なのかとか、URLのサンプルを提示などできますか？もし詳細を記載可能でしたら質問本文に追記してください。質問は`編集`から修正可能です

Comment: URLは社名など入っているので難しいのですが、環境は具体的にどういったものをあげればよろしいでしょうか？

Comment: @anko さん、回答者が問題を再現しやすくなるような情報がたくさんあればあるほど嬉しいです。たとえば今の質問文のままだと anko さんが具体的にどのような操作をなさった上で問題を感じていらっしゃるのか分かりにくいので、作業手順が欲しいです。元々どういう手順で表示できていて、`mv XXX YYY` をしたあとどういう手順を踏むと `File not found` がどこに表示されたのでしょうか。また、そもそも `mv XXX YYY` をしたのはサーバー側でしょうか、そのサーバーはどのようなものでしょうか。　／　ヘルプページ https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask の「忙しい同僚に話しかけているつもりになって～」の部分も参考になりそうです。どうぞよろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: 「開発中のもの」とは何でしょうか？ / 提示されているのはほぼWindows(=クライアント側)の情報ですが、実際に操作しており問題が起きているのはサーバ側に見えます。 / アクセス先は同じIPアドレスのサーバでも、ブラウザ経由で「Webサーバ」にアクセスするのとTereTermで「sshサーバ」にアクセスするのとでは見えるものが違います。 / 「サーバに"/var/www/html/XXX"として置いたものが、ブラウザからは"SERVER_NAME/XXX"として表示できるようにしたい」、といった情報が欲しいです。

Answer (score -1, accepted):

結論：シンボリックリンクで解決
当方の理解不足だった点：IPアドレスはXXXという名前に接続されるように設定されていた、のだと思う
（どの過程で自身がその設定をしたのは理解はできていない、そしてIPアドレスというアドレスの感覚も正直いまいち）

`mv XXX YYY`で名前は変えたものの、XXXという名前のディレクトリは存在していた。
その状況でXXXというリンクにしようとしたが、リンク先の名前と残っているディレクトリが同じ名前ゆえに、衝突してエラー発生。
XXXディレクトリを`rm XXX`コマンドで削除した後、改めて`ln -s YYY XXX`を実行したところ、もとのIPアドレスから、作業中のものが動作確認できるようになった。
`ls`コマンドを打つとXXXがほかのディレクトリとは違う色で出るようになった（ただのリンク名だから）。 unlinkで一度XXXを削除し、また別のディレクトリとリンクさせることも今後可能。

Comment: IPアドレスの接続先はXXXになっている、リンク先に名前をこれにしないと接続できない

Comment: 多分、他の人の役には立たない＋直接的な解決じゃないということで`-1`何だろうけど、マイナス投票した人はコメントで理由を書いてあげてください。自己回答しようとするのは良いことだと思います。……それはそれとして、ホスト名を設定しているのであれば、ApacheやNginxを利用していると思います。そちらの設定は特に問題なかったのですか？設定ファイル内を`XXX`で検索して何も出てきませんか？`XXX`が完全に排除できない理由としては多分公開ディレクトリが指定されているせいだと私は考えています。

Comment: 名前を`XXX`で伏せるにしても、それが何を指しているのかが分からないと他の人が見ても中々理解しづらいです。`/var/www/html`以下のコンテンツなのか、それともwebサーバ関連の設定(`/etc/httpd/*`)を弄ったのか等。

Comment: ホスト名設定自体は当方がやったわけではないので、ApacheやNginxは把握できておりません。

Comment: XXXはサーバ上のhomeディレクトリに入っております。