# シンボリックリンク作成時のエラーを解消したい

Tags: unix

```
ln: failed to create symbolic link ‘xxx/yyy’: File exists
```

英語の資料はたくさん見つけたのですが、これはどういった意味なのでしょうか？
何をすれば解消しましすか？

teratermにSSH接続し、サーバ上で作業しています。

windows10,teraterm

Comment: 関連: 1つ前のご質問です https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/52709/19110

Comment: `ln`は通常ならWindowsに存在しないコマンドなので、質問の説明としては間違っているか情報が不足していると思います。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> File exists

"ファイルが既に存在します" というエラーです。

シンボリックリンクで作成しようとしたファイル名が既に存在しているので、別の名前で作成するか既存のファイルをあらかじめリネームしてください。